# asp.net dropdownlist resetting

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, html-select

I have a weird problem. I have an asp.net page in which I have a dropdownlist/combobox that is databound to a SQL table. The dropdown list is set to display the primary key field which is just an incrementing number starting at 1.

I previously had the whole form working just fine but now I am running to some problems. I have narrowed the problem down to the dropdownlist, a button and the buttons onClick event. When i click the button the dropdownlist reset to the number 2. Currently there are only 3 items in my sql table and thus only 3 numbers (1,2,3) in my drop down list. If I set the list to number 1 and click the button it stays at number 1. If I set it to 2 it stays at number 2. If i set it to anything above 2 it always resets to 2. I have actually removed all lines of code in the click sub so the button click literally does nothing, yet it still resets to 2 if the selected item is higher than that.

Here is my HTML code. Im including it all in case the problem is elsewhere:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SGC.aspx.vb" Inherits="sgc" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
  .auto-style1 {
        width: 181px;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        width: 1px;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        width: 14px;
    }
    .auto-style4 {
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style6 {
        width: 181px;
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style7 {
        width: 4px;
    }
    .auto-style10 {
        width: 182px;
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style11 {
        width: 302px;
        height: 23px;
    }
    .auto-style13 {
        width: 14px;
        height: 23px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:URL(/idle_screen.jpg);">

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table align="center" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style6" ></td>
        <td class="auto-style5" bgcolor="#FF0000" colspan="3" align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#003399" Text="SGC Message Log"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="select sub_id 'ID #', race 'Race', orgMsg 'Original Message', Case when replyMsg like '%' then 'See Reply' else 'Reply' end as Reply, androidID from messages"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style6"></td>
        <td class="auto-style7" colspan="3" rowspan="2">
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" align="center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ID #" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="Vertical" Width="1400px">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID #" HeaderText="ID #" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID #" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Race" HeaderText="Race" SortExpression="Race" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Original Message" HeaderText="Original Message" SortExpression="Original Message" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reply" HeaderText="Reply" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Reply" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="androidID" HeaderText="androidID" SortExpression="androidID" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>

        </td>
        <td class="auto-style10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style6"></td>
        <td class="auto-style10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style6"></td>
        <td class="auto-style11"></td>
        <td class="auto-style5"></td>
        <td class="auto-style5"></td>
        <td class="auto-style5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style4" bgcolor="#FF0000" align="center" colspan="3">
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="MyButton_Click" Text="Refresh" Width="175px" ForeColor="#003399" />
          </td>
        <td class="auto-style10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="902px">

    </asp:Panel>
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Enabled="False" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>

</div>
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="deviceList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ID #" DataValueField="androidID"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">

</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPayload" runat="server" Width="750px" Height="120px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnPush" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="sendtxt" />
<asp:Label ID="lblResponse" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't included any of my visual basic code because none of it seems to have any effect. If someone thinks its needed I'd be glad to post it. Does anyone know why the selected index of my list would reset (but only above 2) when clicking a button that does nothing?

**Update**

Here is my entire VB code-behind file. I've put everything back to where it should be.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class sgc
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ''''    
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

End Sub



Private Function SendNotification(ByVal authstring As String) As String

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", authstring))
    Dim collaspeKey As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")
    Dim deviceList As DropDownList = FindControl("deviceList")
    Dim DGridView As GridView = FindControl("GridView1")
    Dim txtPayload As TextBox = FindControl("txtPayload")
    Dim i As Integer = Convert.toInt32(deviceList.Selecteditem.text)
    Dim reply As String = txtPayload.Text
    Dim race As String = DGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
    Dim orgm As String = DGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text

    Dim payload As String = race + ";" + orgm + ";" + reply
    Dim postData As String = String.Format("registration_id={0}&data.payload={1}&collapse_key={2}", deviceList.SelectedValue, payload, collaspeKey)
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function

Protected Sub sendtxt(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim txtPayload As TextBox = FindControl("txtPayload")
    Dim lblResponse As Label = FindControl("lblResponse")
    Dim deviceList As DropDownList = FindControl("deviceList")

    lblResponse.Text = "Message Sent. Confirmation " + SendNotification("My Auth Key")


    txtPayload.text = ""

End Sub
End Class
```

**Update 2**

I've altered my code to do all the binding myself in the VB. This still does not seem to have helped:

```
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        Dim sqlds As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
        sqlds.ID = "SqlDataSource3"
        Me.Page.Controls.Add(sqlds)
        sqlds.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString2").ConnectionString
        sqlds.SelectCommand = "select sub_id 'ID #', race 'Race', orgMsg 'Original Message', Case when replyMsg like '%' then 'See Reply' else 'Reply' end as Reply, androidID from messages"
        GridView1.DataSource = sqlds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        deviceList.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2"
        deviceList.DataTextField = "ID #"
        deviceList.DataValueField = "androidID"
        deviceList.DataBind()

    End If
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your code-behind, all of it, please.

Comment: Well clicking a button doesn't do "nothing".  At the very least it causes a postback, which means your page will be re-rendered with all that that entails.  Without the code you can't really tell what's going on

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm pretty new to asp.net so I don't fully understand all the differences between the normal desktop programming that I'm used to. I have posted my code

Comment: Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) on button click? You are doing a new request in the browser, then the state will be lost.

Comment: Also...you don't need to call FindControl for every asp control you want to access...just access it directly e.g. `GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text` etc...

Comment: That code is associated with a button I use to reload the page in order to refresh my table/grid. It was something I found on another question here on SO and it seemed like a simple way to refresh the data. But thats not the button I'm having trouble with

Comment: @fnostro I was having trouble getting them to associate, but I will try again. Thanks for that tip

Comment: Whn and whre do u bind it?

Comment: I had been binding them in the HTML/main page. I tried switching to binding them myself in the code. I've added that in the code above. But even with that it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to check the postback at pageload event of yours.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Me.IsPostBack Then Return

End Sub
```

Comment: using `SQLDataSource` is compulsory ? if not i recommend you to bind your dropdown from code behind and call that function on `page_load` `Event` only if a `postback` is done

Comment: No, it's not necessary. I have tried the binding both ways. With and without the code you suggested. It always does the same thing. Thanks for your continued help. Is there a way I can disable the postback all together and only call it manually? This is a form that only I will be using so that would not be a huge deal

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203163/if-databind-is-called-inside-page-load-then-sqldatasource-doesnt-perform-u[link]

if you see the answer over there , it says `sqldatasource` binds before `postback` , so i think you shouldn't use `SQLDataSource` at all. See this [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/asp-net-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdown-list-from-database[link] . Try the method in this example and then call it on `Pageload`.

I myself use this method because i have more control as compare to `SQLDatasources`, that's why I never prefer these `SQLDatasources` .